# Starting AVAudioPlayer when application is in background

Tags: ios, audio, background, avaudioplayer, playback

I have an application with `App plays audio` and `App provides Voice over IP services` options configured in the `.plist`.

The application is receiving socket events (even in background) and regarding the events, plays sound. When the application is in foreground, all is ok. When the app is in background, the app is triggered, the play method of the player is called, but without sound.

I have tried many sample code from Internet but nothing is working. I have tried to start playing sound in foreground and then move my app in background and it's working.

What is the problem to start playing a sound when the app is in background?

Here's my code handling an event when my app is triggered in background:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"HeadspinLong" withExtension:@"caf"];
if (audioPlayer != nil) return;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
audioPlayer.delegate=self;
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: &error];
audioSession.delegate=self;
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVAudioPlayer doesn't start playing in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564298/avaudioplayer-doesnt-start-playing-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an obvious question, but are you actually calling the `play` method on the `audioPlayer` object in your real-life application? Probably at the end of background event handler?

i.e. `[audioPlayer play];`

Comment: The code I have provided is in the "Init method" (called only once). The play method on the audioPlayer is called when the "network event" is coming.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding it seems not possible to start playing a music when the app is in background... It is only possible to continue playing an existing played music in background